# Xcode Check Dependencies Error: OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension requires a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I am brand new to Xcode but paid for GoNative to turn our web app into a native mobile app.  When following [the instructions on GoNative](https://gonative.io/docs#apple-app-store) and using the OneSignal extension I am getting the following error when I try to Archive the app or when I click Play button to test.  I looked in the project editor and I can't seem to find how to get around this error.  I have my iOS certs in xcode but don't know how to add the provisioning profile to the dependency.

Error:

> OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension requires a provisioning profile.
>   Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in
>   the project editor. Code signing is required for product type 'App
>   Extension' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
When selecting Onesignal as target I have the following selected (no option for automatic)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your Xcode Settings -> **General** and observe targets like this. Select **OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension** target and checkmark automatic sign in if you did same for main app also. Otherwise, select provisioning profile related to your app.

[image]

The Same solution is given in GoNative Support. Check it out: [GoNative Support](http://support.gonative.io/knowledge_base/topics/onesignalnotificationserviceextension-requires-a-provisioning-profile)

Comment: for my app i made it manual, do i need to create a provision profile certificate for onesignal ? If yes , how to do it i am new to onesignal.